# How to define static method in a cpp file. (C++)

Tags: c++, header

I wan to have my class in a separate **.h** file, and the implementation in a **.cpp** file. The problem I run into is "Multiple definition of *methodname*". If I put the content of both files in a **.hpp** file it works, but I'm not sure if I should use that.

The .h File:

```
#pragma once

class Nincs;



class Sugar
{
    public:
        Sugar(){}

};

class Nincs : public Sugar
{
     private:
        static Nincs* ins;
        Nincs(): Sugar() {};
    public:
        static Nincs* instance();

};
```

the .cpp File:

```
#include "Sugar.h"


Nincs* Nincs::ins = nullptr;


Nincs* Nincs::instance() //the error is with this line
{
        if (ins == nullptr)
        {
            ins = new Nincs();
        }
        return ins;
};
```

The main .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Sugar.cpp"




using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Nincs* n = Nincs::instance();


    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I am struggling with making a simple singleton class in C++.

Comment: The program compiles fine [here](https://onlinegdb.com/yR_LEJeKT)

Comment: My main is in a different .cpp file, I will make an edit accordingly

Comment: Never include a `.cpp` file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **problem** is that you're including the source file(Sugar.cpp) instead of the header file(Sugar.h).

To solve this inside `main.cpp`, change `#include "Sugar.cpp"` to:

```
#include "Sugar.h"
```

Also it is recommended that **we should never include source files**.

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/S1GAswcQt)

Comment: Thank you for the help, it solved my problem! This was a really dumb mistake of mine...

Comment: @Myxy290 MIstakes do happen sometimes. You're welcome.